# Drag only 2 elements in droppable area

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am working with Jquery draggable in my project I have many elements for droppable in the draggable area but I need to restrict only two elements can we droppable in draggable area

```
$('#uploaded-files-list ul li').draggable
    zIndex: 999
    cancelable: true
    revertDuration: 0
```

how I can achieve this?

**Updated:**

I have one more question if we have multiple droppable places and I want to add only 2 elements in each droppable places the how can we do that??

Comment: Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/qqqm6/

Answer (score 1):

In the `droppable` settings is an [`accept`](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) property. If you provide a function to this you can programmatically check that certain conditions are met before allowing the element to be dropped. As such you can count the number of existing dropped children and return `true` or `false` as appropriate. Something like this:

```
$(".drop-area").droppable({
  accept: function() {
    return $('#drop-container > div').length < 2;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have one question if  we  have multiple droppable places ha I want to add only 2 elements in each droppable places the how can we do that??